# How does Islam view love marriages?

Tags: nikah

Many of the marriage of the prophet was believed to be political or to strengthen relationship between two families. Some can argue that a marriage in Islam can be for supporting a girl (and vice versa to support a guy). I have also read a story in which a girl's father was worried about his daughter marriage and the prophet proposed an old man who was also looking for marriage.

**My question is, does Islam recognize love marriage or the love between a boy and a girl? If yes in what capacity? If marriage can be political, is there a room for love marriage?**

Comment: A Persian quote says: "Instead of getting married lovingly and trying to live the rest of your life wisely, get married wisely and then you WILL find the rest of your life going lovingly." :)

Comment: I assume, the question is about "Love in marriage", not "Love marriage" which is so common these days.

Comment: The question is about encouraging and accepting that fact that a young girl would more likely desire a young guy.

Comment: Please modify your question since the basis of your question is for the rarest circumstances. Ask a general question about 'love in Islam's marriage' and then ask 2nd question about 'the marriage's of the Prophet' Obviously our prophet was and is 1 of a kind...
i.e. if you get the answer of the 1st and then the 2nd it would be great for your answer

Answer (score 4):

#### Update:

It seems the OP didn't asked the love marriage, which is today so common and seems he know the fact that it is prohibited and asking whether Islam recognizes natural love between opposite sex.

Yes, Islam does of course recognize love between a boy and a girl (as long that do not cross the border). Because,

It is Allah himself, which created affection, desire and love between the opposite genders, as he saying

> Beautified for people is the love of that which they desire - of women and sons, heaped-up sums of gold and silver, fine branded horses, and cattle and tilled land. That is the enjoyment of worldly life, but Allah has with Him the best return. [source](http://quran.com/3/14).

and saying this

> Sahih International: And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquility in them; and He placed between you affection and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought. [source](http://quran.com/30/21)

So, I think it is clear, Islam does not ignore this fact. (how can it ignore where Allah is the creator of such things in human nature?)

#### Why prophet proposed an old man?

Though you didn't mention the exact incident, I would say this:

The prophet is the messenger of Allah. Allah reveals many things to his messenger which he does not reveal to any other. May be the prophet saw, future goodness in that marriage with the old man or it may be indicated by Allah.

***But***, the general guideline is not this. Because, once a Sahaba got married and he informed the Prophet. The prophet asked, was she a virgin ( indicating young, same age) or a widow. The Sahaba replied, She was a widow. The prophet then said, "Why didn't you marry a women of same age? " or something similar. [See here](http://sunnah.com/urn/234640)

So, marrying a man or women of same age isn't discouraged by Islam, rather it is encouraged.

---

### Old answer (but I think, still relevant) :

First we need a real good definition on the term "Love marriage". I assume, you are asking about the general practice which involve making friendship with someone and then loving and ... etc.

On that context, I believe, that kind of *Love marriage* is totally unacceptable. My point of reasoning is given below:

1. With this [saying of Allah](http://quran.com/24/30) about lowering your gaze, I don't find a way to make a friendship with someone of opposite sex. Because, making friendship usually very naturally involves at least seeing *(please don't say , some hypothetical concept of making friend)*, then how you supposed to be loving someone, while you are not even allowed to see him/her?
2. If you argue that, Allah prohibits gazing but now loving, then I would say, does it make sense, if your father orders you to not to be with someone and you think it is okay to can send messages,.. etc without physically being near him/her ?
3. "Love marriage" in the context of current age, essentially involve being alone with the loved person, which is clearly prohibited. *(Again, I am realistic and can't dream of any loving pair not being alone, especially in current age)* as recorded in Tirmidhi, #2165.

   > "No man is ever alone with a (non-mahram) women but the Shaytaan is the third one present.”

   See [this similar question](http://www.muftisays.com/blog/mokap/804_04-01-2011/free-mixing-.html) and [this fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=6812).

***But***, If it becomes possible to love a person without seeing him/her, not thinking anything which is not allowed and after some time goes on proposal in appropriate way and marry him/her, then I would say, it will be allowed, because it do not break any rule or order of Allah and his messenger, of course Love can exists without even seeing <sup>1</sup> (intentionally) someone. such as by their quality or good characters etc.

---

<sup>1: I am not saying it is prohibited to see someone with intention of marriage. I am saying about the general looking and gazing things</sup>

For further reading..

- [Turning gaze on sudden fall on non-mahram women](http://sunnah.com/urn/253720)
- [Why dating is prohibited](http://www.brevardmasjid.com/marriage/dating_p.html)

Comment: By love marriage, I meant the natural desire of young girl to find a young guy who is more acceptable and more attractive. They do not have to see each other and talk. Love (or should I say infatuation) can develop just be taking a glimpse of someone.

Comment: I think, in that case the paragraph after ***But*** saying has answer. It is allowed. Also, "natural desire of young girl to marry a young guy who are on the same level and same energy level with her." is natural, so not prohibited. On the other hand, it is encouraged on some degree. Because, the prophet encouraged a Sahaba to marry women of same age. 

About the political point, i think, that should be a seperate question

Comment: Allwed is ok (it is under stable). The question is does Islam `accepts it` that means it recognizes it and encourages a young girl to marry a young guy. Or marriage are simply political deal which does not care who you like or who you don't.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter see the update. :) of course, marriage is not political!!! How can it be?

Comment: What does "cross the border" mean here?

Comment: @MarcGravell It means, being on the boundary defined by Allah i.e not doing something not allowed in Islam

Comment: @AnwarShah this is a decent question, but you need to make it more specific -- like quoting the hadith about marrying a virgin correctly. +1

Comment: the word bikr is translated as virgin there, thayyab as previously married. and you translate bikr as of same age. i do not think it has that meaning. i think a virgin there can be ten years younger, even if five, it is not same age. she can also be older.

Answer (score -2):

Islam has never allowed love marriage.

Because it is prohibited to even just see to non-maharam before marriage not hearing the voice of non-maharam .

So how can you call it love without seeing and mutually talking to your potential spouse...? The Qur'an allows to marry women, but the Hadiths prohibits adultery. I assure love marriage is an obvious sin.

Allah stated in holy Qur'an:

> You don't approach to grave sins.(Al-Israh)

The scholars of thafsir declared that the grave sins is indicated to include fornication.

Comment: Welcome tp [islam.se]. Please provide some reference to backup your answer. When you quote anything from the Quran make sure you state the chapter and the verse or provide a link to it. And please properly format your answer and make it more presentable. Go through [answer].

Comment: Salaam Bro, I've tidied up your answer, but I've not added any references. Could you please add them for the Quran (Surah and Ayah), as well as your tafsir.

Comment: there is a hadith about looking before marriage for marriage